# Inserting new RawContact without setting Dirty flag to 1

Tags: android, android-contacts, rawcontacts

I'm working on an app which Syncs contacts with a backend. When you delete the app the contacts will be deleted, but when you re-install the app the contacts will be restored from the backend. 
After initial sync I don't want the contacts to be synced again because no data has changed. Therefore I use `uri.buildUpon().appendQueryParameter(ContactsContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER, "true");` when inserting a restored RawContact.
But the Dirty flag is still set to 1, so the contacts will be unnecessary synced back again. How can I prevent this?

I even set `builder.withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.DIRTY, 0);` the dirty field to 0 when inserting but this does not help.

I thought of adding a custom data for a initialsync flag, but the editing of the contacts can be done outside of the app so I can't set this to false when someone edits the contact outside of the app.

Comment: please post your answer if were able to solve it